# sangria query returning IntType

Tags: graphql, sangria

I'm trying to perform query agains my local graphql server defined in Sangria. I have mutation defined like this:

```
val Mutation = ObjectType(
"Mutation", fields[DAO, Unit](
  Field("addMovie", IntType,
    arguments = Title :: Genre :: IMDBLink :: Nil,
    resolve = ctx => ctx.ctx.addMovie(ctx.arg(Title) , ctx.arg(Genre), ctx.arg(IMDBLink)))
)
```

But when I'm trying to perform query against it, I'm receiving either Syntax error with this query:
    `mutation addMovieQuery {addMovie(title: "asd", genre: "asasdqw", IMDBLink: "$imdbLink") {}}`

Or `Field 'addMovie' of type 'Int' must not have a sub selection` when running query with id inside brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a field returns an `Int` or any other scalar, as the error says that field cannot have a subselection. Scalars and enums are the "lead nodes" of a query, so you cannot select additional fields on them. Try this instead:

```
mutation addMovieQuery {
  addMovie(title: "asd", genre: "asasdqw", IMDBLink: "$imdbLink")
}
```